# Custom Exceptions String Array

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I'm building a custom exception which basically is thrown if an array doesn't contain 5 strings. This is what I have so far. The only exception that really matters is the custom one as I just have to show that that exception is thrown if the array doesn't contain the 5 strings after the input file was split. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
package exceptions;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exceptions {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input, formattedInt, field[];
        int recordNumber = 0;
        int length;
        Scanner inputFile;

        try {
            inputFile = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
            while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
                recordNumber++;
                formattedInt = String.format("%2d", recordNumber);
                input = inputFile.nextLine();
                field = input.split(",");
                length = field.length;
                if (field.length != 5) throw new CustomException(field.length);
                System.out.println("Record #" + formattedInt + ": " + input);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error! Problem opening file.\nError was: " + e);
        } catch (CustomException ce) {
            System.out.println(ce);
        }
    }
}
```

CustomException.java

```
package exceptions;

public class CustomException extends Exception {
    private int fieldcount;

    public CustomException(int fieldCount) {
        super("Invalid Count: " + fieldCount);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return fieldcount;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I may have to add another try/catch block but I'm not sure. Pretty new to exceptions.

Comment: What's the question? Are you asking why your code doesn't pass compilation?

Comment: Yeah, it keeps saying I don't need the 2nd catch but then the exception will never be printed.

Comment: Reverse the order of the catch blocks. The more specific one (the subclassed exception) must come first!

Answer (score 4):

`CustomException` extends `Exception` so any `CustomException` will be caught in the first catch block.

Rearrange your blocks so the `catch(CustomException e)` block comes before the `catch(Exception e)` block

Comment: You should mark his answer as the solution if it fixed your problems :)